# Change default image path in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a Joomla website with another server I use for the images. But now in the editor the images are not shown because it loads from the relative url. Is there a possibility to change that the image paths gets change?

Example:

"/images/image.jpg" -> "http://images.domain.com/images/image.jpg"

As you can see the correct url is just the same url but with the http://images.domain.com put in front of it.

I tried to find it myself but I couldn't find anything of value. I saw that you can change the relative urls in the TinyMCE initialization but that won't fix my problem. I need to add that subdomain in front of it.

I don't mind using a script or anything to change the url after everything is initialized, I just want it to work.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

There are potentially a variety of ways you could solve this issue.  If people are using the TinyMCE `image` plugin to insert images there is a specific option for this:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/image/#image_prepend_url

If Joomla has some custom built way to insert/manage images that option likely won't work as it is specific to the `image` plugin.

TinyMCE also has a variety of URL handling configuration options:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/url-handling/

These may allow you to resolve this issue as well.

Lastly, you could rely on TinyMCE APIs to know when content is about to be placed into the editor.  You could then inspect that HTML for images and adjust the URLs as needed.  For example:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector:  '#myTextarea',
    editor.on('BeforeSetContent', function(e) {
        console.log('BeforeSetContent: ' + e.content);
        console.log(e);
        // The variable e.content is what will be inserted in the editor.
        // You can modify that as needed before TinyMCE does the insertion.
        // This is a simple example but shows the idea.
        if (e.content.startsWith('<span class="mention"')) {
            e.content = e.content + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: You might like to join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and keep half an eye on the tinymce tagged questions there.

Comment: @HuubS I am not a Joomla person so I don't know where in Joomla the TinyMCE init takes place.  I would think you could get that answer on the Joomla Stack Exchange site reference in the comment above from mickmackusa.